# Jquery - highlight div / grey out rest of the page

Tags: jquery, fadeout

I'm trying to highlight div / grey out rest of the page. The code I have is:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
$('.entry-content').mouseover(function(e) {
$('.expose').mouseover(function(e){
    $(this).css('z-index','99999');
    $('#overlay').fadeIn(300);
});
});

$('.entry-content').mouseleave(function(e) {
$('.expose').mouseleave(function(e){
    $('#overlay').fadeOut(0, function(){
        $('.expose').css('z-index','1');
});});});});
```

HTML looks like

```
<div id="overlay">
<div class="entry-content">
  <div class="expose">something</div>
  <div class="expose">something</div>
  <div class="expose">something</div>
</div>

#overlay {
background:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
display:none;
width:100%; height:100%;
position:absolute; top:0; left:0; z-index:99998;
}
```

What I'm after is as long as the user hovers over the entry-content div, leave the page greyed out and highlight the div he's hovering over.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: You could clone the div you want to highlight and show it in a modal dialog using jQuery dialog right above the same position the original div is at. The dialog feature has a `modal` property you can set to true which should gray out the rest of the screen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `z-index` is relative to the the stacking context, not relative to the document. If you want the `expose` element to appear over the overlay, they must either be siblings, or you must explicitly position `.expose` using `position:*`.

In general, the elements must be part of the same stacking context in order for their z-index values to be compared. You can learn more about stacking contexts [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Understanding_z-index/The_stacking_context).

Some additional points:

1. You should make the overlay transparent to pointer events. You can do this by using `pointer-events:none;`
2. You do not need to bind to `.expose` when the container is moused over. Bind the handlers in parallel with the handler for showing/hiding the overlay

Here is the corrected code. You can see a working demonstration [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sMw5D/):

**CSS:**

```
#overlay {
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    display:none;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:99998;
    pointer-events:none
}
.expose{
    background-color:red;
    position:relative;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$('.entry-content').hover(function() {
    $('#overlay').fadeIn(300);
}, function() {
    $('#overlay').fadeOut(300);
});

$('.expose').hover(function(e) {
    $(this).css('z-index', '99999');
},function(e) {
    $(this).css('z-index', '1');
});
```

Comment: I have expose div se to position:relative. The code works, but the page doesn't stay greyed out, when hovering between the expose divs.

Comment: @user1049961 Is something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/qc2um/) what you needed?

Comment: Thanks, even in your example there's the "blinking" problem when hovering between the divs. I would like to have the page grey as long as I hover over content of entry-content, and just change the div highlighting... Any ideas?

Comment: @user1049961 Are you looking at the current example? My last update had that problem, this one stays gray as long as you're anywhere in the container (even when switching between elements inside the container).

Comment: One more question though: is it possible to animate the highlight fadeout? I mean, can I animate the z-index change? Or is there any other/better solution?

Comment: @user1049961 In that case you are better off going with something like the other answer, modified to use transitions: http://jsfiddle.net/QN7pM/6/

Answer (score 1):

you could simulate this behavior without an overlay and using CSS3

[example jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QN7pM/4/)

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="entry-content">
      <div class="expose">something</div>
      <div class="expose">something</div>
      <div class="expose">something</div>
    </div>
</div>​
```

```
html, body, .wrapper {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

.wrapper {
    -webkit-transition:all 300ms;
    -moz-transition:all 300ms;
    -ms-transition:all 300ms;
    -o-transition:all 300ms;
    transition:all 300ms;
}

.wrapper:hover {
    background:rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}

.wrapper:hover .expose {
    background:#ddd;
}

.entry-content {
    padding:6px;
}

.expose {
    margin-bottom:6px;
    padding:12px;
    border-radius:3px;
    background:#eee;
}

.expose:hover {
    background:#fff!important;
}
​
```